# Number of field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

If I know the index $(\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times} : (\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times})^n)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is it possible to know how many field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $n$ there are?

This seems to work for $n=2$. I'm not sure in general. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't there be infinitely many extensions of $\mathbb Q_p$ of degree $n$?

Comment: @IanColey No, because of Krasner's lemma, which states roughly that the field extension cut out by a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is locally constant as a function of its coefficients.

Comment: You can use the quotient group you mention to count the number of *cyclic* extensions of degree $n$, in the case that the $n$-th roots of unity are already there downstairs. This would work, for instance, in counting the cyclic cubic extensions of $\mathbb Q_7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That index is very easy to calculate, since $\mathbf Q_p^\times \cong \mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z_p^\times \cong \mathbf Z \times \mathbf F_p^\times \times \mathbf Z_p$. So you might as well be asking how many extensions of a given degree $\mathbf Q_p$ has, without any assumptions on what is known.

The answer is, in general, quite difficult. I don't know of any simple formula. If you're willing to count extensions with weights other than $1$, there is a very nice *mass formula* of Serre which you can find by searching the literature.

Abelian extensions of $\mathbf Q_p$ are easier to count, by using the Artin reciprocity isomorphism of local class-field theory. This is why it works well for $n=2$. You might want to start there.

Otherwise, the question is much more difficult. The absolute Galois group of $\mathbf Q_p$ is quite a beast (though much less of a beast than the Galois group of $\mathbf Q$).

Comment: A general formula counting the number of extensions of given degree of a local field has been established by Krasner. It is engraved on his tomb in the Père Lachaise cemetary in Paris .

Comment: @nguyenquangdo Very interesting! I was in that cemetary a couple of years ago, I didn't know Krasner was buried there. Do you happen to have a reference for the formula?

Comment: A general formula counting the number of extensions of given degree of a local field (with a given discriminant ?) has been established by Krasner. It is engraved on his tomb in the Père Lachaise cemetary in Paris .